# What function to close the search dialog in Android?

Tags: android

Using the function super.onSearchRequested(), I can open a search dialog in my Android application, what is the equivalent function to close it ?

Comment: Did you get a valid answer till now ?

Answer (score 2):

The search dialog is closed with `setOnDismissListener()` and/or `setOnCancelListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it ...

```
import android.app.SearchManager;

((SearchManager)this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE)).stopSearch();
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#stopSearch().

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to hide the search bar with ICS with this method ?